# Exceljs Currency Format Issue for German

Tags: reactjs, exceljs

I would need to have currency format for a cell as **€4.000,00**, I have tried everything but not working.
The format I have tried as below.

> 1. €#.###,##00 2. "€"#.##0,00 3. \€#.###,##00 4. \€#,##00.00

`worksheet.getColumn('AK').style.numFmt = '"€"0.###,##00'`

Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm late but I found the solution:

All you have to to is format the field but first, check if the field is parsed to float either it wont works.

> worksheet.getColumn('AK').numFmt = '€ #,##0.00';

I hope this can help you. It's works for me.